# How can I put List in WHERE for Linq-to-NHiberbnate query if it has nulls in it?

Tags: c#, sql, nhibernate, filter

I'm using nHibernate and trying to make query.

Example:

I have `List<Entity>` - this will be entities to filter

I have `List<int?>` - this will be filter with values of some Entity.SomeId field

this list will contain values: 0,1,2,3,null

I want to make query like this:

```
List<int?> filters;//1,2,3,null
List<Entity> entities; // some entities
Entities.Where(entity => filters.Contains(Enentity.SomeId)).ToList();
```

nHibernate makes query(kind of):

```
select * from entities where entity.someId in (....);
```

result: returned all filtered records i need except entities where `entity.SomeId == null`

What's wrong with it? is there some workaround for such stuff?

Comment: I'd suggest looking at the editing help before your next post: http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help  It's actually much easier than you think.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would use a compound condition and use a list of `int` instead of `int?`.

```
List<int> filters;//1,2,3
List<Entity> entities; // some entities
Entities.Where(entity => entity.SomeId == null
                           || filters.Contains(Enentity.SomeId))
        .ToList();
```